# Reverse proxy on pfSense 2.1.5 with Squid

Tags: reverse-proxy, pfsense

I installed Squid on my pfSense and I am trying to reach 192.168.1.41 when the request is for sub1.dom.it, and I am trying to reach 192.168.1.42 when the request is for sub2.dom.it.

I used to have all traffic to dom.it going to 192.168.1.25 with the following NAT rule: 
[image: NAT rule]

I tried to add the following reverse proxy configuration, but nothing has changed, as all traffic is still going to 192.168.1.25.

[image]

If I disable the NAT rule, I get a connection timeout on sub1.dom.it and I cannot reach 192.168.1.25 anylonger.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you are mixing url redirection and network NATting (but maybe I missunderstood the you are trying to achieve.

I guess the you are looking for is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23084547/how-to-redirect-custom-urls-to-some-local-ips-with-pfsense) in another stackoverflow question

Comment: When you **remove the 1:1 translation**, you have no point of ingress to your network. What you ask for is that external requests hit the reverse-proxy when asking for HTTP or HTTPS. You need to **perform port forwarding** from the external IP ports 80(TCP)/443(TCP) to 127.0.0.1 to the port the reverse-proxy is configured to listen on.